# Can't access Files in /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/elants_i2

Tags: drivers, hardware

I have bought a new Laptop, had set it up, installed Manjaro and followed the Entry in the Arch-Wiki on how to get the touchpad working. (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_15are05#Touchpad) Worked fine. Then, dont ask me why, I wiped the HardDrive and installed Arco, now I cant follow the Arch-Wiki Tutorial anymore, cause I cant access the files which I have to Edit.
What I tried:

- Edit, Sudo edit, su - then edit,
- Change File ownership to me, then edit, give myself `chmod 777` permissions then edit

With all these attempts at trying to edit the file, I always ran into the problem, that the Program doesnt stop writing to file. It just goes on and on. Vim doesn't show it, it just freezes, but NANO says its writing and freezes then.
Then I ran some other Commands in hope I can get this stuff back:

- chattr, lsattr give both this Err: `Operation not supported While reading flags on /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/elants_i2c/unbind`

I honestly don't know anymore, I guess I can change all Permissions and Ownerships back and give up on the touchpad, but maybe someone here has an Idea :` )

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I cannot comment because I have too few points.

I've experienced this issue myself in the past with files and (don't ask me why) just editing the files with a plain GUI text editor worked for me when I saved the file.

Also the CLI text editor `micro` tells you `Permission denied` and prompts you if you want to save the file using `sudo` if you don't have sufficient permissions. Might be worth a try.

-Cheers